# How to put a gradient on a path in illustrator cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, gradient

I would like to take a signature or letters created with illustrator, scan or photograph the signature, bring the signature into illustrator, vectorize it, run a path down the center of the letters, and then run a gradient on the path.

I know this can be done,I've spent 8 hours on youtube videos finding so many thing close to what I want but not exactly. Please help.

Comment: It'll be easier if we can see what you're trying to do. Can you find any examples online that are close to what you want? Or maybe edit your question to include a screenshot of how far you've gotten and why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Select the stroke and apply a gradient. That's all there is to it.

[image]

You can then use the `Gradient Panel` to adjust as you'd like.